# Datatable get button on each row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, datatable

I have 2 buttons in each row in a column 'action' in a datatable. Each button on different rows have same class but different data-id. I want to click one of the buttons in each row from jquery to simulate button click. I am trying to loop over the datatable and get the buttons on each row but failed to get it.

Please check the ss.

[image]

```
$('#apply-all').on('click', function (e) {
            var table  = $('.mydatatable').DataTable();
            table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
                  var data = this.data(); // able to fetch the data.
                  //how to feth the button on this row?
            } );
        });
```

Comment: Could you share the HTML code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [node](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().node()) function `.node()` function to get the element of the selected row. Then you can wrap it in jQuery to perform jQuery actions on it like this:

```
    $('#apply-all').on('click', function (e) {
        var table  = $('.mydatatable').DataTable();
        table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
              var data = this.data(); // able to fetch the data.
              var row = this.node();
              var rowJqueryObject = $(row);
              //or
              $(row).find('button'); //will return all buttons in that row
        } );
    });
```

Comment: Thanks gaganshera, I will check that too. I have a question, I have a view of 25 in data table and when I get the table intance I get only 25 count whereas the data is more than 25.

Comment: What do you mean by table instance?

Comment: var table  = $('.mydatatable').DataTable();

Comment: also when I am doing:   var buttons =   $(row).find('button');    button[0].click();   it only clicks the button in the first row and not other. And the button click event makes an ajax call.

Comment: `button[0]` specifies the first button it finds

Comment: Yes, but it will should for every first button in every row. When ever i am calling the click function an event is generated and ajax call is made for the first row first button only. When I make async false to ajax method it works but hangs the page until each row button click method is completed